# loop prematurely quitting

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

This loop works fine but prematurely quits at times. I set a piece of code in it so that I can view the random number. It only closes prematurely when the random number is equal to the highest numbered question the user inputs

(Example...a user wants 10 questions, if the random number is 10 the program quits.)

I have no idea why since i have it set to if(random number <= the number of questions)

```
for ( int loop = 1; loop < loopCount; loop++ )
{
   aa = r.nextInt ( 10 + 1 );
   abc = ( int ) aa;

   String[] userAnswer = new String[x];

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, abc );

   if ( abc <= x )
   {
      for ( overValue = 1; overValue < forLoop; overValue++ );
      {
         userAnswer[j] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( null, "Question " + quesNum + "\n" + questions[abc] + "\n\nA: " + a[abc] + "\nB: " + b[abc] + "\nC: " + c[abc] + "\nD: " + d[abc] );

         if ( userAnswer[j].equals ( answers[j] ) )
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, "Correct. \nThe Correct Answer is " + answers[abc] );
         }
         else
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, "Wrong. \n The Correct Answer is " + answers[abc] );
         }//else

      }//for

   }//if

}//for
```

Comment: The loop doesn't work fine if it closes prematurely.

Comment: Looks like you have picked your answer. But later, please learn how to give meaningful variable names. What the hell are aa, abc, and x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you may have an array out of bounds at the last line shown:

```
            String[] userAnswer = new String[x];

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,abc);

            if(abc <= x)
            {
                for(overValue = 1; overValue < forLoop; overValue++);
                {
                    ... questions[abc] ... a[abc] ... b[abc] ... c[abc] ... d[abc] ...
```

If the arrays `questions`, `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` are of size `x` (as `userAnswer` is), indexing them with `x` causes such an exception.

You should have a condition of

```
            if(abc < x)
```

and preferably you should also adjust the random generation:

```
aa = r.nextInt ( x );
```

Comment: out of bounds? I don't get it, sorry. j is set to the random number, so it should be userAnswer[randomNumber to draw from an array]

Comment: @Nick, sorry, the first version was quoting the wrong part of the code, Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Wait though, doesnt x make the length of the array? x is defined as the total number of questions the user wants, so i claimed x in the array so as if the user wants 10 questions userAnswer would be String[10]

Comment: @Nick, as others mentioned as well, Java arrays are zero-based, so if `yourArray.length == x` then you can legally index elements `0..x-1` within the array. Referencing `yourArray[x]` would thus cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the outer for loop:

```
for (int loop = 1; loop < loopCount; loop++) {
```

or the inner for loop

```
for (overValue = 1; overValue < forLoop; overValue++);
```

Both the for loop has problem because the initial number should be 0 not be 1. And another problem is that the second for loop end with ;, so it will not do anything at all

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that array indices start from 0 and go to length-1.  If the length is `x`, the highest index is `x-1`, so when the input is exactly `x` and you try to index into the array, it will fail.

The condition should be `abc < x`

Comment: That fixed the main problem. It now is working without exiting. Now its being wierd. I type in the correct answer and it tells me im wrong...but I'm right. 

Example: I type in c and I know its right...it should compare c to c and come out 0 and if they equal...should spit out Correct! 

yet im getting a Wrong! The Correct answer is c.

It made me wtf.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you've got forLoop and loopCount from, but it looks like the for loops are off-by-one. I'd usually write either for(x=0;x<X;x++) or for(x=1;x<=X;x++).

I don't think this is your actual problem, but it's something to check.